# Executing simple postman code check - returns 'Cannot read property 'code' of undefined.'

Tags: postman

I'm trying to write some test for REST API and started from POST request. 
I tried to do some simple test from Postman guides:

```
pm.test("Successful POST request", function () {
    console.log(pm.response.code)
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([201,202]);
});
```

And get

```
Successful POST request | TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined
```

But the status seems to be ok:
201 Created
286ms
920 B

So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What version of the Postman native desktop app is this from?

Comment: version. v7.10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dumb as hell. I just realized that I posted my tests to wrong Tab - Prerequested scripts instead of tests.